# When you remember some past sweet memories and want to mention to them

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Suppose you are recalling a sweet memory from the past and you remember a specific person / event in which you e.g. laughed / was very happy a lot. How would a native call that moment / event / person / scenery etc. at the time being (when he / she is remembering it)? The only way I think it should be translated from my mother language is:

> - May it always be brought happily to mind.

I would be thankful if you help me find the best way to say it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you think about pleasant memories, you can describe it as [reminiscing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reminisce).

You can refer to the memories as **reminiscences** or, if you really want to lay it on thick, **sweet reminiscences.**

These expressions are regarded as quite old-fashioned, but I think the whole concept is quite old-fashioned. I can't imagine a sk8er boy doing it.

Comment: Thank you, but what do you think of what Max mentioned in the previous post? Does it make sense to you or you believe that it sounds old-fashioned too?

Comment: @A-friend: I'd say that both _cherish_ and _reminisce_ are about equal. The difference is that reminiscing is more closely related to the concept you originally asked about. You can cherish a lot of things without reminiscing; the two become very similar when you're cherishing _memories._

Comment: @J.R. so what should I say using "reminiscing" to mention those sweet memories which are gone and belong to the past time?

Comment: You can say, "I am reminiscing about Bob. I miss his big smile." Or, "I've been reminiscing about that vacation we took to Switzerland. Remember how beautiful those mountains were?"

Comment: @A-friend, cherish is definitely in decline, but reminisce has made a comeback over the past century. As J.R. says, you can cherish a lot of things: it 's only when you cherish memories that it has the meaning that you are looking for. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cherish%2C+reminisce&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccherish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creminisce%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I don't know if it's old fashioned.I chatted with my old college roommate and we did a lot of reminiscing - I'm not sure what other word I would use for it that means the same thing. Or maybe it's just the act of remembering out-loud that's old fashioned in the era of social media. I went to college before the invention of the selfie-stick :P

Answer (score 12):

You might be looking for *fond memory*.

> [fond memory](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/fond-memory)
>   something that you remember with pleasure
>   fond memory of: *Jane has fond memories of a happy childhood.*

You might also be interested in *cherish*.

> [cherish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cherish)
>   : to remember or hold (an idea, belief, etc.) in a deeply felt way

So,

> May I always cherish these fond memories.

Comment: She fondly remembered that summer evening from so long ago.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the terms **Sentimental** or **Nostalgia**

> Nostalgia - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nostalgia   a wistful
>   desire to return in thought or in fact to a former time in one's life,
>   to one's home or homeland, or to one's family and friends; a
>   sentimental yearning for the happiness of a former place or time: a
>   nostalgia for his college days.

> Sentimental - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sentimental expressive
>   of or appealing to sentiment, especially the tender emotions and
>   feelings, as love, pity, or nostalgia